# Pandas change every other row to a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of images. For every image, there's a list of 48 landmarks and for every landmark, there're x/y coordinates.

The data frame needs to be of a specific shape:

[image]

Right now the shape is as follows:

[image]

I cannot find a way how to get the data to the needed format - could you, please, help?

Comment: Could you maybe add the list you have so we can better see how the format is. You should use images, if they are possible to avoid.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
#if first column is not index
#df = df.set_index('first_col')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack(0)
```